# Do azure push notifications only work for operations done from the client?

Tags: azure, windows-8, push-notification

We were trying to implement a system using which we will issue notifications when we insert some tuples in our database, they seem to be working fine when the inserts were done through the app but not elsewhere. My question is, Do push notifications only work when CRUD operations are performed from the app? And not elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you registered the push notification for your apps insert ([Update The Insert Script](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-dotnet/#header-2)). Whenever the app inserts data, the script is executed and pushes the notification.
However, if you write data using a method that doesn't invoke your customized insert script, no notifications will be sent.

Links where to start implementing Pushes in WCF:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2011/01/18/windows-phone-7-azure-and-push-notification-tutorial-series-in-c.aspx
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WCF-Horse-Race-f22b99ff

Comment: Yes, its actually WCF that does the write, any way to invoke the customized script? How do the news/sports Win8 app work then? Do they poll?

Comment: You have to invoke the push from within your WCF.